# <util:properties not injected in java @controller on webapp deployed using eclipse WTP

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, properties, code-injection, eclipse-wtp

I am developping a maven project using spring mvc. I have a problem with accessing properties () using @value. when i start tomcat 6, I get the following exception :

```
09:21:21.703 ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resultsDisplayController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private int foo.ResultsDisplayController.PAGE_SIZE; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'appProperties' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) ~[spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) ~[spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) ~[spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) ~[spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3830) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4337) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566) [catalina.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_21]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_21]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288) [bootstrap.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413) [bootstrap.jar:na]
```

Here is my foo.resultsDisplayController

```
@Controller
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class ResultsDisplayController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResultsDisplayController.class);

    @Value("#{appProperties.page_default_size}")
    private int PAGE_SIZE;

@RequestMapping(value = "/show-results", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayVariousreults(Model model) {
...
}

}
```

the content of servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:component-scan base-package="foo" />

    <annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

<!-- properties -->
    <util:properties id="appProperties" location="classpath:app.properties" />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" />

    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="language" />
        </beans:bean>
    </interceptors>

    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basenames">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>classpath:labels</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="5" />
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <beans:property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="order" value="0" />
        <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <beans:entry key="xml" value="text/xml" />
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationListener"
        class="foo.AuthenticationListener" />
</beans:beans>
```

the content of app.properties : page_default_size=10

EDIT:

I doscovered that the problem is related to eclipse wtp. When I deploy the webapp on tomcat using eclipse the problem occurs. However, when I deployed the war ganarated by maven on another tomcat server independently from eclipse, I don't get the problem and the application works fine. The question is how to fix this eclipse wtp bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `<context:property-placeholder location=".." />` and then `@Value("${property}")`

Comment: The tag that you gave me was not detected by eclipse. I used this tag <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties" />. Now I get this compilation exception : Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${page_default_size}"

Comment: that's odd - this combination works fine for me.. (apart from the misspelled file name). Are you sure your bean and your xml are the same context?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by same context. But I know that the meesagesource, the authentication provider and the other beans work correctly

Comment: this tag works thanks :)<context:property-placeholder location=".." />

Answer (score 0):

"NumberFormatException" i think it reads the value as string.Maybe you can change the type of PAGE_SIZE to String,and then convert it to int.